# How can i fix NextRouter not mounted error while deploying Next JS 13 app to vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm deploying my Next js 13 app, but it is throwing an error

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib'`

and Next Router not mounted error

```
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
    at useRouter (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/5225.js:12428:15)
    at useHybridHydrate (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/5225.js:6566:45)
    at Object.useWrappedStore (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/5225.js:6614:9)
    at AuthProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/9622.js:219:31)
    at Je (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:121:272)
    at Je (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:127:11)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
    at Ke (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:131:155)
    at Je (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:122:215)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
```

for the first error i've checked another stackoverflow question which suggest to do `npm add -D encoding`. and i did that but no change. also for the second error i'm not using the old `next/router`, instead i'm using `next/navigation` but it still not doing it correctly. can anyone help?

[EDIT]

i've debug my app and the error is coming from `nextWraper` when used with redux. i'm only using that b/c i've created multiple slices in my app.

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import menuReducer from "./slices/menuSlice";
import vehicleReducer from "./slices/vehicleSlice";
import blogReducer from "./slices/blogSlice";

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  menu: menuReducer,
  vehicle: vehicleReducer,
  blog: blogReducer,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
});

const makeStore = () => store;

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

and in layout.js

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthProvider";

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  //new change
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
export default RootLayout;
```

authProvider.js

```
"use client";
import React from "react";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { SkeletonTheme } from "react-loading-skeleton";
import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import NextTopLoader from "nextjs-toploader";

export function AuthProvider({ children, ...rest }) {
  const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ChakraProvider>
          <NextTopLoader color="#008080" showSpinner={false} />
          {children}
        </ChakraProvider>
      </Provider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

i've been using the redux provider inside layout.js but in deployment it was showing an error so i moved it to authProvider.

Comment: can you run the project locally for more verbose logs? It would be useful to know what code/file is throwing the error

Comment: @Undo i think the error is coming from `nextWrapper` package for redux. i've posted the redux in my code.

Comment: `next-redux-wrapper` does not support Next.js 13 `app` folder structure. See https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/494#issuecomment-1366851492.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm add -D encoding
```

Will install it as a dev dependency. Since you experience a problem when you deploy the app, I suggest you try the following instead:

```
npm add encoding
```

That might solve your first error. Let us know if it worked.